# Can I use a Sharepoint view in an iFrame on an external website/app that has users autheticated with Azure AD SSO

Tags: azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, cross-domain, sharepoint-online

We have a new intranet site that uses our AzureAD credentials with SSO (via SAML2.0).  There's a widget that can display personal or specific Sharepoint Document folders but I've found that this is lacking in detail - particularly some of the document metadata.

Is there a way to use a curated Sharepoint View in an iFrame on this cross-domain website?
At present when I try, it comes up with an error

> Refused to display "sharepoint-site-page" in a frame because it is set
>   'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'

I'd be grateful for any assistance if possible.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this applies to your particular view, 
however this is a pretty well known thing that microsoft locks down sp to not allow cross site iframing by default, 
you could try this solution:
https://www.sharepointpals.com/post/how-to-bypass-cross-domain-issues-to-display-sharepoint-online-pages-within-iframe-from-an-external-domain/

it makes use of the allowframing tag, that microsoft allows to do exactly that. 
as per : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/officeapps/iframing-sharepoint-hosted-pages-in-apps

hope this helps you a bit.

Comment: Thanks!  I'd read through that first article you linked and had already made a start down that road, but I ran into difficulty with the way Microsoft have obfuscated previous settings like getting access to Master Pages and the like.

Comment: Ya that article is mainly for individual pages, but you are looking at doing it for master pages, there's a link in there that tells you what to do to the master files, but doesn't tell you how to get to them. I believe the only way to get to them is to download the sharepoint designer, easiest guide i've found so far is to follow this to get the spdesigner https://collab365.community/use-sharepoint-designer-2013-sharepoint-2016-online/